what is scratch.img.0000 and how to reduce size of this file
After use 'adb remount', there will be a large(11G) file named scratch.img.0000 in /data/gsi/remount.
It seems that this file is used as overlay fs (/mnt/scratch), how to reduce the size of it.
/data/gsi/remount # ls -l
total 11138156
-rw-r----- 1 root root          17 2024-07-12 09:21 scratch.img
-rw------- 1 root root 11405463552 2024-07-12 09:21 scratch.img.0000

After adb enable-verity, the file was deleted, but all modification after adb remount was recoverd.

Android non-development questions questions (how to use apps, flash devices, ...) should better be posted on https://android.stackexchange.com

After read the source code of aosp13,
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/heads/android13-release/fs_mgr/fs_mgr_overlayfs.cpp
It shows that it will use half of /data size as overlay disk, so it is ok.
static inline uint64_t GetIdealDataScratchSize() {
    BlockDeviceInfo super_info;
    PartitionOpener opener;
    if (!opener.GetInfo(fs_mgr_get_super_partition_name(), &super_info)) {
        LERROR << "could not get block device info for super";
        return 0;
    }
    struct statvfs s;
    if (statvfs("/data", &s) < 0) {
        PERROR << "could not statfs /data";
        return 0;
    }
    return std::min(super_info.size, (uint64_t(s.f_frsize) * s.f_bfree) / 2);
}

